# Google visualization Data Table header event

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am not able to trigger event when header is clicked in google visualization table.

I have disabled the sort in the DataTable.

http://jsfiddle.net/xj3ww79n/

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {
      alert('Hi');
    var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
    alert('You selected ' + data.getValue(row, 0));
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".google-visualization-table-tr-head").click(function(){
   alert("You selected the header."); 
});
```

See your updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xj3ww79n/2/